# Set formulation of Induction proof

Tags: logic, induction, set-theory

[Source: Patrick Suppes' Axiomatic Set Theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ega.png)

My question is why go through all this proof procedure rather than write a proof by contradiction assuming that the property doesn't hold for $A$, as in there exists at least one member $x_0$ that doesn't have the property. We then can use the premises to reach a contradiction, namely (iii) by taking $x=x_0$ and $B = 0$, giving us that the property holds for the union and thus specifically for $x_0$. A contradiction is reached.

I think the flaw here is that I'm assuming unwarranted things about the structure but what exactly?

Comment: Please don't use images: they are not searchable (either within SE, or in general web search engines), and they are not accessible: users who rely on screen readers cannot read what is in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument isn’t sufficient to prove the result. If you take $x=x_0$ and $B=0$, (iii) tells you that $\varphi(\{x_0\})$ holds, but that’s not what you want: you want to know that $\varphi(A)$ holds.

Comment: Yes, but I first assumed φ(A) to be false (with x0 as a witness) and then reached φ({x0}) to be true: a contradiction.

Comment: @MohamadHusseinNaim: That is not a contradiction. It would be a contradiction only if $A$ were $\{x_0\}$, in which case there would be nothing to prove anyway. In order to get a contradiction from assuming that $\varphi(A)$ is false, you must prove that $\varphi(A)$ is true, and showing that $\varphi(\{x_0\})$ does not do that.